# Session timeout after 15 minutes

Tags: session, mobile, timeout, oracle-adf

In my application I use web services to get required information. To actually use this services you have to login first, you get your token - encrypted password, afterwards this token is attached to SOAP requests to identify current user. The thing is, when you do not use service for 15 minutes, your token changes and when you are trying to obtain another bunch of information from the server it denies old token. As a result app do not get required information and throws a heap of errors.

How to send user (load Login.axm) to Login page when token has been changed?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you, Shay Shmeltzer for your answer.

How I solved this problem:

1) First I read how does sessions work in my particular case. I used stateless session which means -

> A new session is opened for an initial request and the session remains
>   open for subsequent requests. Relogin occurs automatically
>   (transparent to the user) if the session is closed. UsernameToken and
>   PasswordText must be included as SOAP headers in the initial request
>   to open a stateless session.
>
> Stateless session management is the best method to use for high-load
>   Web service applications. Using Stateless mode, the application
>   provides the username and password only once, that is for the initial
>   request. A session is opened on the server and is dedicated for this
>   user.
>
> In the response Siebel Business Applications return the SessionToken,
>   which is an encrypted string containing the information about
>   username, password, and timestamp. For subsequent requests the
>   application must use the SessionToken to reuse the session.
>
> For security reasons SessionTokens are regenerated for each response.
>   The application must provide the last received SessionToken for the
>   next request.
>
> The SessionToken-Siebel session map is maintained in the Siebel Web
>   Server Extension (SWSE); based on the SessionToken value SWSE sends
>   the request to the correct Siebel session (task).
>
> Although the session is persistent, authentication happens for each
>   request (SWSE decrypts the UserName and Password from the
>   SessionToken).

the main problem was :

> NOTE:  Reconnecting or automatic logging in again will only happen if
>   the token has not timed out. If it times out, then the user must
>   manually log in again. Token timeout must be greater than or equal to
>   session timeout. For more information on session token timeout, see
>   Session and Session Token Timeout-Related Parameters.

in my case standard session token live time was 15 minutes.

That is why I included counter in my code and checked it before each request. If counter time > 15 minutes, I sent log in request to the server to get new session token. The reason, I did not change current page to log in page straight away after the counter exceeds 15 minutes is: place in code, where I check counter is already initiated by the bindings to get required value to render it, so if your token has expired you will get a heap of errors. That is why firstly I renew the session sending log in request, get active session token and put it into the last request which is requested by binding. After app renders page without any errors, it shows pop up message "Session has expired" and goes to log in page.

Answer (score 0):

You can programmatically set the soap header being sent to your SOAP service from ADF Mobile - http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37975_01/doc.111240/e24475/amxwebservices.htm#CHDIBIIE